# Are there any ways to use function_Pointer in this case?

Tags: c++

i'm struggle to know how ios::hex function works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   
#include <ios>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>


class A {
public:
 A& operator >> (std::ios_base& (*pf)(std::ios_base&)) {
     (*pf);
     return *this;
 }
 A& operator >> (int& a) {
     std::cin >> a;
     return *this;
 }
};

int main() {
 int b;
 A a;
 a >> std::hex >> b;
 std::cout << "입력 : " << b << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

the point is,   (*pf) is not a way to excute 'ios::hex function'

std::ios_base& hex(std::ios_base& str);  : str  -> i don't know how to give this parameter like " pf(??) "

so i decide to convert more easy way and figure out how to work.

```
namespace yy {
    int sum(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
class A {
public:
    A& operator >> (int (*pf)(int,int)) {
        pf;     // ---> 
        return *this;
    }
    A& operator >> (int& a) {
        std::cin >> a;
        return *this;
    }
};


int main() {
    int b;
    A a;
    a >> yy::sum >> b;   // or a >> yy::sum(4,5) >> b ;  ???
    std::cout << "입력 : " << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but, still i don't know how to use it..

hepl me please

Comment: Change `(*pf)` to `pf(cin)` might work?

Comment: @AlanBirtles   sorry, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::hex` is used to set `std::ios_base::flags`. Your class `A` isn't derived from `std::ios_base`, nor does it have a member that's derived from `std::ios_base`. So there's indeed no obvious place to store the `std::ios_base::hex` flag.

The code suggests you want to affect `std::cin::flags`. That's a bit strange, as `cin` doesn't really belong to a particular `A` object. But let's assume that is what you want. Then you can just write `std::cin >> pf`

Comment: now i fully understand how it does works. all thank to you